# How do I connect to a shared folder on the network on Fedora 23?

Tags: linux, fedora, webserver

I'm new to Linux and I'm trying to learn about it. I usually connect to my university server on Mac OS X using the "connect to server" option. This is an example of my university home address:

```
smb:\\home.something.something.edu\Myusername
```

and once I get connected to it, I am prompted with a dialogue box for username and password. I tried using `ssh` and my server address, but I believe this is not the right process. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fedora documentation is your best friend here... They have an answer to how to connect to an SMB share.

URL: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-samba-connect-share.html

1. Open Nautilus
2. In the address bar type your SMB URL (as you've written)
3. You may be prompted to authenticate with your University username, password and domain.
4. You should now be able to see your network share content

If you want persistent connections to your network share or for it be connected when you power on/log on then you will need to look at either scripting it or delving into to complex world of FSTAB.

Comment: I could successfully connect to the server through the help of GUI, but i believe if you need to master Linux you need to know how to do everything through terminal. Hence do you have any suggestions on how to learn to do things through terminal in general (not just this situation). Like an online documentation for command line or a book. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this answer i generic for all *NIX envirements because when it comes to networking, protocoll is more important than programs / envirements..
As long as the protocol is well implemented, your client does not matter, as long as it "speaks" the protocol..

Judging by the URI your university is using a windows share (SMB).
First of all you should explore if there is an other fileserver protocol available, for instance you could use fish or scp if you can log in by SSH.

However, most *NIX has an implementation of SAMBA (https://www.samba.org/), wich is an SMB/CIFS server and client.
Most of the "windows share" applications in LINUX depends om SAMBA.

So depending on your DE (Desktop Envirement) there are several ways to access your share.

The most generic way however would be to mount your share somwhere in your /mnt/[sambasharename] directory..

1. install SAMBA using your package manager (Fedora uses RPM / Yum right?)
2. take a look at your distributions samba documentation and choose your prefered method..

you could now just mount it as root se unoficcial documentation http://www.oregontechsupport.com/samba/ or use FUSE to mount it as a user..

However, if you are using KDE, GNOME or an other DE it should find the share if SAMBA is installed on your system.

Good luck